How to show that for linear systems, global asymptotic stable if and only if global exponential stable?
Definition: An equilibrium point $p$, ($p$ not necessarily $0$) is globally exponentially stable if, for all initial conditions $x(0)$, there exists $\alpha, \beta > 0$,
$\|x(t) - p\| \leq \alpha e^{-\beta t} \|x(0) - p\|$
It is well known that any linear time invariant systems $\dot x = Ax$, global asymptotic stability iff global exponential stability.
But how do I show this result?
I tried substituting in the solution on the left-hand side,
$$\|x(t) - p\|  = \|e^{At} x(0) - p\|$$
I wish to pull out $e^{At}$ and bound it, but this seems to be impossible due to the $p$ term, which is preventing me from pulling out the $e^{At}$.

This result is also true for linear time-varying systems (with uniformity assumptions). See for example "Linear Systems Theory" by Wilson J. Rugh for the proof.

Since it's linear, you can assume $p=0$. If $p\neq 0$ were an equilibrium point, then so would $\lambda p$ for $\lambda \in\mathbb R$ and $p$ would not be asymptotically stable.

Actually, you only need homogeneity of degree 1, and you can prove that attractivity to the equilibrium (let's say $0$) is equivalent to global exponential stability.

If the equilibrium $p$ is globally asymptotically stable, then $p=0$. Therefore, we are just interested in the convergence of $x(t)$ to 0 as $t$ goes to infinity.
There are many ways to prove that. Here I will be using no prior knowledge of stability conditions for linear systems.
Define $z(t)=Px(t)$ and we get $\dot{z}(t)=Jz(t)$ where $J=PAP^{-1}$ and we can pick that matrix $P$ such that $J$ is of the form $J=\mathrm{diag}(J_1,\ldots,J_m)$ where the $J_i$'s are all Jordan blocks of the form
$$
J_i=\lambda_iI+N_i
$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the i-th eigenvalue and $N_i$ is the nilpotent matrix of the Jordan block.
Now, we have that $$z(t)=e^{Jt}z(0)=\mathrm{diag}(e^{\lambda_1t}e^{N_1t},\ldots,e^{\lambda_mt}e^{N_mt})z(0).$$
where all the exponentials of the nilpotent matrices are, in fact, matrices polynomials in $t$.
Therefore, assuming that the system is asymptotically stable, then this implies that all the $e^{\lambda_it}e^{N_it}$'s are converging to zero. For this to happen we need that all the $\lambda_i$'s have negative real part.
In fact, we can also see that
$$
e^{J^*t}e^{Jt}=\mathrm{diag}(e^{2\Re[\lambda_1]t}e^{N_1^*t}e^{N_1t},\ldots,e^{2\Re[\lambda_m]t}e^{N_m^*t}e^{N_mt})
$$
showing that $e^{J^*t}e^{Jt}$ goes to zero exponentially fast in this case.
This implies that the state goes to zero exponentially fast as well and that asymptotic stability implies exponential stability.
